# FailureFlash with Passportjs and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Im trying to flash error messages on failed login (ExpressJS 4.2 and PassportJS)

My code is:

//Admin Route =====

```
router.get('/admin', function(req, res) {

    res.render('admin', {message: '', user: ''});

});
router.post('/admin', passport.authenticate('loginAdmin',{  successRedirect: '/panel',
                                                failureRedirect: '/admin',
                                                failureFlash: true })

);
```

//Passport local strategy =====

```
passport.use('loginAdmin', new LocalStrategy(

  function(username, password, done) {



    modeloUsuario.findOne({ nombre: username, password: password }, function(err, user) {



      if (err) { return done(err); }

      if (!user) {

        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username.'}); //Error to show
      }



      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

But "message" in get request of /admin never gets replaced with "Incorrect username."
Am I doint it wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What failure message do you get instead?

Comment: @bencripps that's not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're redirecting back to `/admin`, and in the `/admin` route handler you're setting message to an empty string.  Your admin route handler fires after your passport strategy, so you're clearing the message out there.